# Can onbeforeunload event be watch by $watch in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am a newbie of angularjs and now I am stack on catching event of onbeforeunload event. I would like to show to some response to user when they leave the page. And I would like to watch onbeforeunload event by $watch and execute my message display function.

But how can I watch that event? 
Could anybody please answer me?
Thank you very much.

Comment: What version of Angular do you have?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-beforeunload

Comment: @MrH Angular 1.3 latest stable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function( event ) {
    var answer = confirm("Your message....");
    if (!answer) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

With $watch which I think you don't need it in here. Something like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
        return $location.path();
}, function(newPath, oldPath){
   // Compare it, and trigger your message function.
})
```